# Regex to get all lines past last detected string

Tags: c#, .net, regex, text, match

I have this text:

```
Blah
Blah
Blah
Blah //// CODE --- do not change Blah
Blah
Blah
Blah
Blah //// CODE --- do not change Blah
I
Want
This
Text
Matched
```

I want to match just this part of it (all lines after the **last** `//// CODE ---` detected):

```
I
Want
This
Text
Matched
```

I have tried with `(?<=\/\/\/\/ CODE ---).*`, [but this is no good](http://regex101.com/r/tF4gD6/1). I'm missing some sort of trick, I think. Anyways, what is a regular expression that will match the text I want? I am working in .NET (C#).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex with multiline and dotall flags and grab captured group #1:

```
\A.*//// CODE ---.*?$\s(.+)\z
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/oD2qM1/1)

Comment: If this were reduced to just .*//// CODE ---.*?$\s(.+), would it still be valid?

Comment: Yes that regex `.*//// CODE ---.*?$\s(.+)` will still work without anchors `\A` and `\z`

Comment: In fact, even this: .*//// CODE ---.*?$(.*) I think this one is my favourite.

Comment: Yes `.*//// CODE ---.*?$(.*)` will work too but will start the captured group with a new line.

Answer (score 2):

Use the below regex and get the text you want from group index 1.

```
.*(?<=\/\/\/\/ CODE ---)[^\n]*\n(.*)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tF4gD6/2)

OR

```
[\S\s]*(?<=\/\/\/\/ CODE ---).*\s([\s\S]+)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tF4gD6/3)

Through negative lookahead.

```
(?:\/\/\/\/ CODE ---[^\n]*\n)(?!.*?\/\/\/\/ CODE ---)(.+)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tF4gD6/5)

Comment: Is there any way to not use \n explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use this regex

```
.*\/\/\/\/ CODE ---.+?\n
```

with multiline and dotall flag and replace with empty string